# How can i change the color of particular row of a datagrid

Tags: c#, .net

i am going to bind a datatable to the datagrid
i just want to change the color of a particular row of datagrid based on the value on datatable row. i need c#/.net code for it

Comment: For info, it is a good idea to state winforms/wpf/sl/asp.net/mvc/ etc when referring to UI controls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
this.dataGridView1.Rows[RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
```

Or if you want to it over a mouse move event

```
private void DataGridView1_CellEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Style.SelectionBackColor = Color.Red;
}

private void DataGridView_CellLeave1(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Style.SelectionBackColor = Color.Blue;
}
```

Also, [Change individual DataGridView row colors based on column value](http://www.codeproject.com/tips/51128/Change-individual-DataGridView-row-colors-based-on.aspx) might help.

Answer (score 2):

The grid view features a sort of hierarchy of properties that control style.  A good overview is here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1yef90x0.aspx

But most simply, you can likely set the `DataGridViewRow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor` property for unselected rows and the `DataGridViewRow.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor` property for selected rows.

Comment: I think you mean SelectionBackColor, not BackColor, which will set the background color of rows that are *not* selected.

Comment: @Paul good spot.  It's early in the morning and I hadn't spotted that in the question :)

Comment: i am going to bind a data table to the datagrid.

Comment: i just want to change the color of a particular row of datagrid based on the valulue on datatable row. i need c#/.net  code for it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the appearance of selected rows based on the contents of the rows rather than the selection state, this is how I'd do it:

```
   private void DataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (RowShouldBeRed(e))
        {
            e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightPink;
            e.CellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Red;
        }
        else
        {
            e.CellStyle.BackColor = DataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor;
            e.CellStyle.SelectionBackColor = DataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor;
        }
    }
```

In this example, the RowShouldBeRed funciton is a stub for the logic you would use to determine how to color the row.

Answer (score 0):

**// For a Particular Cell**

```
dataGridView1.Rows[RowIndex].Cells[ColumnIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

**// For a Particular Row**

```
dataGridView1.Rows[RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Black;
```

**// For a Particular Column**

```
dataGridView1.Columns[ColumnIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor =Color.Yellow;
```